# Timestamp: How do I extract the individual component in a timestamp field in Oracle NoSQL Database?

Tags: nosql, oracle-nosql

I am exploring the SQL queries on JSON documents that has a timestamp field called lastVisited.

Here's an example:

```
    "lastVisited" : "2020-11-21T20:33:39.8125"
```

My application would like to extract individual component of the timestamp. For example, we want to individually extract the year, month, day, hour, and minute.

Does Oracle NoSQL Database support functions that do that?

Answer (score 0):

There are several timestamp query functions for this: year(), month() etc.
See [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/other-databases/nosql-database/22.1/sqlreferencefornosql/functions-timestamps.html#GUID-2AC9DF50-96E3-43DD-A2CC-3E0F49EE1751) for all the details.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).